# React - useState / useEffect and JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

New to React.

I'm trying to pull some data from an API (results are JSON) and then update setNavItems with the JSON response.  I'm then trying to iterate over those results with navItems.map but nothing is being returned.

Would anyone be able to take a look and tell me where i'm messing up?

```
function NavTop() {
const [navItems, setNavItems] = useState([]);

async function getAPI(){

    const url = '/v7/workorders/65378'
    const x =  await fetch(url,{headers: newHeaders}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => setNavItems([data]));

    return x;
}

useEffect(() => {
    getAPI();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="navTop"> 
        
            {navItems.map((item) => (
                <div className="navTop_item">
                    <NavItem
                        key={item.PK}
                        name={item.PK}
                        count={item.PK}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}

    </div>
)
```

}

After messing around a bit and following the info below the final solution was

```
function NavTop() {

const [navItems, setNavItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
     const getAPI = async () => {
        const url = '/v7/workorders/65378'
        const res = await fetch(url, {headers: newHeaders});
        const data = await res.json();
        return await data.Results;

      }
    
    getAPI().then(res => setNavItems(res))
}, []);

return (
    <div className="navTop"> 
        
        {navItems.length > 0 && navItems.map((item, index) => (
            <div className="navTop_item">
                <NavItem
                    key={index}
                    name={item.PK}
                    count={item.PK}
                />
            </div>
        ))}

    </div>
 )
```

}

export default NavTop;

Comment: try `console.log(data)`, see what's u get??

Comment: When data is an array, you don't need to do `setNavItems[data]`. Now you are storing an array inside an array.

Comment: What is `return x;` supposed to do? Where does it return to?

Comment: The code presented could work depending on what the API returns. I'd log `navItems` and check wether the API call succeeds from the network tab. Currently, without an [mre] it is impossible for us to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested pattern is to define your async call that includes side effects inside useEffect and then invoke setNavItems where appropriate.

```
function NavTop() {

    const [navItems, setNavItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
         const getAPI = async () =>
            const url = '/v7/workorders/65378'
            const res = await fetch(url, {headers: newHeaders});
            return await res.json();
          }

        getAPI().then(res => setNavItems(res))
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="navTop"> 
        
            {navItems.length > 0 && navItems.map((item) => (
                <div className="navTop_item">
                    <NavItem
                        key={item.PK}
                        name={item.PK}
                        count={item.PK}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}

        </div>
     )
}
```

Comment: Using this code and nothing was populated for the props.  I commented out the setNavItems and i did a console.log and i was able to get an array back.

Comment: Here's a snippet of the array that was returned .   Shouldnt i be able to use item.PK to access PK?     {
    "PK": 65378,
    "ID": "65378",
    "Reason": "4/9 - John J is handling order and installation of this window. %0D%0A%0D%0AAmy, see labor report and advise.%0D%0A%0D%0Afront window wonts close%0D%0A%0D%0Areq Security/owner verbal",

Comment: Also,  getAPI().then(res => setNavItems(res)).then(console.log(navItems)) returns [] length 0 .  However  getAPI().then(res => console.log(res)) returns the correct array.  I thought then wouldnt be run until after the previous then had completed successfully?